# Card With TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I design the card view  inside the Textformfeild this is my sample code which consists of the card view with country picker and text form field it is not working

```
Card(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 65,
                          width: 300,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                        child: CountryPicker(
                                          dense: false,
                                          showFlag:
                                              false, //displays flag, true by default
                                          showDialingCode:
                                              false, //displays dialing code, false by default
                                          showName:
                                              true, //displays country name, true by default
                                          showCurrency:
                                              false, //eg. 'British pound'
                                          showCurrencyISO: true, //eg. 'GBP'
                                          onChanged: (Country country) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _selected = country;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          selectedCountry: _selected,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                        height: 50,
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                      ),
                                       TextFormField(
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          counterText: "",
                                          labelText: "Mobile Number",
                                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: can you edit your question to format your code with the code tag?

Comment: Can you share UI ?

Comment: what are the specific difficulties that you are experiencing? Also, please provide the code in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added one extra row and column widgets. Also, you have to wrap the TextFormField inside the Expanded widget to provide it the as much as space it can gain.

You can try it with the below code,

```
Country _selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5.0,
          child: Container(
            height: 65,
            width: 300,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: CountryPicker(
                    dense: false,
                    showFlag: false,
                    //displays flag, true by default
                    showDialingCode: false,
                    //displays dialing code, false by default
                    showName: true,
                    //displays country name, true by default
                    showCurrency: false,
                    //eg. 'British pound'
                    showCurrencyISO: true,
                    //eg. 'GBP'
                    onChanged: (Country country) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selected = country;
                      });
                    },
                    selectedCountry: _selected,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  height: 50,
                  width: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      counterText: "",
                      labelText: "Mobile Number",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I think it will work surely.